# Is Wonder Woman also a speedster just like the Flash and Superman?

Tags: dc, comics, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, justice-league-2017

In this video from *Justice League* (2017), you can see that Wonder Woman saw bullets in slow motion before dodging them. I have seen her stopping bullets, lasers, etc. on her bracelets before (e.g. Justice League cartoons), but I always thought it had to do with instincts and weapon's direction, motion, etc.

Although such slow motions can be meant for viewers, if you look at the end scene in the video, she actually acted like the Flash. A terrorist fired at civilians using automatic assault rifle at close range in large arc and she stopped all bullets while moving not just her hand but also her legs.

I am unable to buy it because this makes Wonder Woman deadly. Unlike Flash, Wonder Woman is physically strong as well as a warrior. She could have crushed Steppenwolf and his minions in no time without Superman. Also, movie never focused on her speed abilities.

Is Wonder Woman really a speedster? Is this consistent with the comics and TV shows?

Comment: "I am unable to buy it because it makes Wonder Woman deadly." Umm...yeah?

Comment: Instead of being super-fast, she may know where the bullet is _going to be_, and start positioning her hand ahead of the bullet arrival, or even before the shot is fired. A form of prescience, in other words.

Comment: @Adamant Because, you know, she wasn't deadly before

Comment: She's not canonically a speedster, but her ability to keep pace with a machine gun has been explicitly shown before:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFtDOvU6c28

Comment: Is Superman an actual speedster? Last I heard, he was fast, but did not have a cassified speedster-energy.

Comment: In the 1978 Saturday morning cartoon series, "Challenge of the Superfriends", on an episode called 'Secret Origins of the Superfriends', the story shows Wonder Woman's origin and it is stated that she has the strength of Hercules and the speed of Mercury. Then it shows her outrun a gazelle?

Comment: That poor teller she pushes out of the way of that bullet at the end. I wonder what kind of fractures he has from that. That couldn't have been a light shove at that speed...

Comment: She's not a "speedster", and neither is Superman (though he's really fast).  Barry Allen is MUCH faster than even Superman in the comics, though he hasn't reached that level in the TV show yet.  The Flash from the movie is ... non-existant, as far as I'm concerned. :)  The problem with comic powers is that they have to be able to tell a story first and powers tend to grow over time to make stories more and more epic.  Superman originally was "faster than a locomotive" (so, as fast as a modern sports car?)  and "able to leap tall buildings in a single bound".  He didn't fly at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It depends what you mean by the term 'speedster'.

If you're asking whether Wonder Woman has superhuman speed or not, the answer is a definite "yes". The DCEU version of Diana clearly shows it in your video clip, and the comicbook versions of her have been stated and shown to have it on multiple occasions.

The original, early [Pre-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Pre-Crisis) / [Earth-Two](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-Two) version of [Wonder Woman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Diana_of_Paradise_Island_(Earth-Two)) was stated to possess "the speed of [Mercury](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mercury_(Roman_god)_(New_Earth))" in her very first appearance in *[All-Star Comics #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/All-Star_Comics_Vol_1_8)*. This was stated again in the first issue of her solo series, *[Wonder Woman Vol 1 #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_1)*.

> As lovely as Aphrodite — as wise as Athena — **with the speed of Mercury** and the strength of Hercules — she is known only as Wonder Woman, but who she is, or whence she came, nobody knows!
>
> [image: All-Star Comics #8, page 59]
>
> <sub>*All-Star Comics #8* (January, 1942)</sub>

The later Pre-Crisis / [Earth-One](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-One) Wonder Woman actually bested Mercury in a footrace, in *[DC Comics Presents Vol 1 #41](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_41)*.

> [image: DC Comics Presents Vol 1 #41, page 29]
>
> <sub>*DC Comics Presents Vol 1 #41* (January, 1982)</sub>

The [Post-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Post-Crisis) / [New Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Earth) version of [Wonder Woman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Diana_of_Themyscira_(New_Earth)) was granted speed and flight by [Hermes](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Hermes_(New_Earth)), as part of her origin story in *[Wonder Woman Vol 2 #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_2_1)*, and was stated to possess "superhuman speed and reflexes" in *[Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe #26](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Who%27s_Who:_The_Definitive_Directory_of_the_DC_Universe_Vol_1_26)*.

> Wonder Woman possesses superhuman strength and the ability to fly. **She also has superhuman speed and reflexes,** and can move swiftly enough to deflect bullets with her silver bracelets.
>
> [image: Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe #26, page 7]
>
> <sub>*Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe #26* (April, 1987)</sub>

And the current, [Rebirth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Rebirth) / [Prime Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Earth) version of [Wonder Woman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)) was ranked in seventh place among DC's fastest characters (ahead of [Godspeed](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/August_Heart_(Prime_Earth)), [Shazam](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Shazam_(Billy_Batson)), and [Kid Flash (Wallace West)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wallace_R._West_(Prime_Earth))), in *[DC Nation Vol 2 #2](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Nation_Vol_2_2)*.

> 7 WONDER WOMAN
> "Diana is the greatest warrior in the DC Universe. She was trained by the Amazons. She understands the mechanics of running better than anyone else on this list, which gives her an edge over the competition."
>
> [image: DC Nation Vol. 2 #2, page 26]
>
> <sub>*DC Nation Vol. 2 #2* (September, 2018)</sub>

---

If, however, you're asking whether Wonder Woman is *in the same league* as the [Barry Allen](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flash_(Barry_Allen)) or [Wally West](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Flash_(Wally_West)) Flashes in speed, or whether she's *as adept at using her speed* as they are, then the answer is a definite "no".

In *[JLA #43](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_43)*, Wonder Woman challenged the Flash (Wally West) to a friendly race, and it was shown that he could stay ahead of her while running backwards.

> [image: JLA #43, page 8]
>
> [image: JLA #43, page 9]
>
> <sub>*JLA #43* (July, 2000)</sub>

In *[JLA Classified #17](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA_Classified_Vol_1_17)*, Wonder Woman noted that although she was "very, very fast" compared to a normal mortal, the Flash (Wally West) was an "indistinct blur" compared to her.

> WONDER WOMAN: Compared to a normal mortal, I'm very, very fast. Compared to me, the Flash is an indistinct blur.
>
> [image: JLA Classified #17, page 14]
>
> <sub>*JLA Classified #17* (April, 2006)</sub>

And in [Wonder Woman Plus Jesse Quick #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Plus_Jesse_Quick_Vol_1_1), [Jesse Quick](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jesse_Chambers_(New_Earth)) noted that although Wonder Woman possessed the speed of Hermes, she lacked "the skill of someone for whom speed was their weapon".

> JESSE QUICK: My studies have mever shown conclusively how fast Wonder Woman is -- but I know she has the speed of Hermes. How that stacks up to the speed of Savitar, I don't know... but without the skill of someone for whom speed is their weapon... Wonder Woman is at a distinct disadvantage.
>
> [image: Wonder Woman Plus Jesse Quick #1, page 22]
>
> <sub>*Wonder Woman Plus Jesse Quick #1* (January, 1997)</sub>

---

In regard to Wonder Woman's speed not being focused on in *[Justice League (2017)](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_(film))*, it's much the same in the comics, and it applies to Superman as well. Those characters who possess super-speed as one facet of a broader power set (i.e. Superman and Wonder Woman) tend not to use it as consistently as those who rely on it as the sole weapon in their arsenal (i.e. Flash or Quicksilver).

I think comicbook writers make the same calculation you have -- that if beings as strong as Superman or Wonder Woman were to use their super-speed constantly, they'd be damn near unstoppable -- and consequently, they just don't *write* them as using their speed constantly, or even that frequently. And if you're looking for an in-universe explanation for that, none has been given to the best of my knowledge.

I recall a Marvel Comics editor, Tom Brevoort, being asked a question along these lines in relation to the Marvel Superman knock-off, [Gladiator](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kallark_(Earth-616)), and he described it as just a "conceit" of the medium that such characters don't use their super-speed as efficiently as they could on paper.

Answer (score 36):

Wonder Woman's ability to bounce bullets off her bracelets requires her to have some superhuman reaction ability; she has to be able to recognize where the bullets are going and move her limbs to parry them with superhuman swiftness.  So she does have a degree of superior speed, which also shows up in, for example, her running speed; she often shows the ability to run faster than normal humans (but this would be expected, based just on the super strength of her legs).

However, she does not typically have *super speed* identified as a distinct power.  For example, the [Super Powers Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Powers_Collection) action figures has cards as part of their packaging that listed the heroes' and villains' powers.  Wonder Woman's does not list super speed.

[image: Super Powers Collection]

Comment: I'd say that "extraordinarily acute senses" answers this question. She has insane *reflexes*, but not insane *speed*>

Comment: Also couldn't "Can bounce bullets off her bracelets" kinda indicate super speed or something? Out of curiosity...

Comment: @Odin1806 Isn't that what I said?

Comment: You did, but I was referring to you showing that the action figure had no such identification. That says to me more that she would not be identified at all as having such an ability... just pointing it out... that's all...

Comment: @vaxquis "Senes" and "reflexes" are not the same thing.  Just because you can see something moving doesn't mean you can move faster than it.  Though from a biological standpoint we wouldn't expect a strong sense to not come with some ability to do something with it.  Diana's not exactly biological, though.

Comment: So she can run at super speed if we shoot at the ground and she tries block every bullet with her toes nail? but she can attchieve the same speed by her self?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I never said they *are* the same thing - I only said that acute senses strongly imply acute reflexes instead of superspeed here. Also, FWIW, as you mentioned yourself, [senses and reflexes *are* strictly connected in the biological sense](http://www.ndcbrain.com/presentations/0-6ReflexesandSenses.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT**

- Something I completely forgot to mention that a buddy reminded is that Wonder Woman's bracelets are also limiting her abilities. So while wearing the [Bracelets of Submission](https://www.cbr.com/wonder-womans-bracelets-15-things-you-need-to-know/) her abilities are already suppressed. So whether or not she wants to hold back, while wearing them she already is...

**TLDR**

- Wonder Woman is a God from the get-go in the DC Extended Universe (DCEU)
- She was not always a God in the comics; but that doesn't mean she didn't always kinda have it.
- Maybe she received the enhanced abilities after her resurrection and become a Goddess.
- And of course... Gods have every right to be "deadly"

So in the DCEU Wonder Woman has been re-branded as a God. This is how she was able to defeat Ares. As Ares explained to her in Wonder Woman (2017):

> Only a God can kill another God.

That would mean in and of itself that within the DCEU Wonder Woman is the "strongest Avenger." The only question to answer then is by what standard is she a God? Diana herself even seems to go along with the idea that Superman is the key to defeating Steppenwolf.

Just as Thor is only seen as a God by humans and is not a God in reality, Diana could be in a similar situation. We do not know by what standard she is classified as a God. Given that she killed Ares, Gods can die. If there is another that could be on the same level as Diana and kill her, then they too would be classified as a God in that instance.

Perhaps Superman can be classified as such. Or perhaps, despite having greater strength and etc. he could not kill Diana even given his best effort. We do not know the answer... yet.

But, Wonder Woman was not always a God as can be seen [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)) sourced from the first comics. She received gifts from the gods, but was only the soul of the first woman killed by men reincarnated. Receiving these gifts would not make her a God, only something altogether unique. She only became a Goddess after being resurrected.

However, of those gifts given as a child, she received wisdom, strength, and speed. This is of course not documented in a calculable fashion and I am unsure if in the old comics she ever shows off super speed, but arguably the only time she would **need** to display this would be against Superman or Flash. Perhaps, just as we know Superman is always holding himself back, Wonder Woman is as well.

Comment: The official name is [DCEU = DC Extended Universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe)

Comment: Score. Thank you!

Comment: The whole "bracelets of submission" thing hasn't been considered part of standard WW canon for a few decades now, generally relegated to the "Yeah, we don't mention that any more for obvious reasons" like the old weakness of how she becomes utterly helpless when someone manages to get a piece of string around her.

Answer (score 5):

Wonder Woman is one of those heroes whose powers have changed greatly over the years. She occasionally has had the power of flight, but in the sort of "carried aloft by the winds" variety, which implies she couldn't fly that quickly.

As others have said, she has super fast reaction time in order to be able to deflect bullets.  While she is clearly moving very quickly in that clip, super speed has never been listed as a discrete power.

The best guess might be that she's a sprinter - she can put on bursts of speed to close a distance quickly, but may not be able to engage in a long-distance run like Superman or any speedster can.

This may explain the need for the invisible/robot plane in the comics - she can run or fly to travel short distances, but for a long haul, the plane is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Diana has frequently been shown to have superhuman speed, which people realized was sort of logical given her superhuman reflexes. For instance, in the TV series she chases after a speeding car and at one point have her running in slow motion, which was the standard visual trope for "running at superhuman speed (see *The Bionic Woman* and *The Six Million Dollar Man* for other examples).

No, I'm sure that the filming of her running from the front was *entirely* about indicating superhuman speed and had no ulterior motives whatsoever, as you will note if you observe closely... and... um... sorry, where was I? Right, superspeed.

The thing is, lots of comic book characters are portrayed as having superhuman powers that aren't usually considered part of their standard power set because in comparison to other super/meta/mutant/whatever humans, it isn't that impressive. In his debut MCU film, Captain America ran down a car and easily tore a door off it, yet if you asked someone to list his powers "superspeed" and "superstrength" wouldn't normally be on the list, because people would, consciously or not, compare him to the people he hangs out with. Compared to Thor or the Hulk, he's not much stronger than an average human. Compared to Quicksilver, he's not much faster than an average human, yet compared to the average human (see the "On your left" jogging scene from *The Winter Soldier*) he's clearly superhuman.

On the DC side, Diana hangs out with the Flash. She might be able to trivially run down cars and move almost faster than the eye can see in short bursts, but compared to Barry Allen or Wally West or Jay Garrick or Bart Allen, well, that's cute.

Comment: Plus one for the slow mo. Because of science.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I remember reading somewhere that Wonder Woman can move at speeds up to 1/2 the speed of light. That would be 93,141 miles per second, which far exceeds the speed of any bullet. Another thing to also consider: She only manifests her "super abilities" when they are most needed, not when she chooses. At least this is what I have deducted from the comics, TV shows, etc. This keeps her humble, in a sense.

Comment: This doesn't answer whether or not she's a speedster in Justice League.

Answer (score 0):

Speedsters use the speed force and can do feats like reach light speed level, go backwards in the time, go through matter and other things a geek can relate deeply

Superman can only reach around the sound speed level, and Wonder Woman something similar... Sorry but the flash that you saw in JL movie, is a bit leveled down.

People tend to compare both because when Superman/WW use their sound level speed, it looks like they're capable of similar things to the Flash , but it isn't the case...

Comment: [Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_(1978_film)) can also turn back time.

Comment: Superman and Flash once raced at lightspeed in *Justice League* animated series..

Comment: The speed of sound is slower than your typical rifle fired bullet so if WW is *merely* the speed of sound then she couldn't have performed the feats in the movie.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor You can't run as fast as a ball, but you can catch one. Unless she chases bullets in the movie, it isn't necessarily a contradiction.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that's true, you make a good point.

Comment: @WhiteWidow: Are you sure that Superman and Flash were traveling at the speed of light during that race? If they were traveling at the speed of light, then they'd circle the Earth 7.5 times in one second. The "finish line" for the race is 100 circles around the globe, so the whole thing should be finished in just over 13 seconds if either one travels at the speed of light. I'm pretty sure they're not going that fast in the episode.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder Woman has been stated to keep up with the Flash in regular cruising speed but not at top speed, but the thing is, since her powers come straight from the speed god, shouldn’t she be much faster? I mean Hermes is the fastest out of all of the gods and can travel much faster than the speed of light.

It has also been stated that Hermes could be faster than the Flash. Shazam, for example, gets his speed from Hermes also, well, his Roman counterpart, Mercury, though still the same person. Shazam can keep up with all of the Flashes and is actually faster than Superman, as stated in many of his comic books, but why doesn’t this apply to Wonder Woman? They get their powers from the same source.

I’m guessing that if the writers wanted to, they’d make her and Shazam be in the same speed category. But then again, sometimes the writers make Wonder Woman and Superman faster than Shazam. It’s always hard to know, and plus, Wonder Woman holds back much more than both Superman and Shazam, since she has her Bracelets of Submission.

So could that be limiting her speed? I mean, it limits her strength and durability, and also gives her a few more abilities. I’m guessing this is the only logical explanation, because DC has not given me a better one.

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer by [editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing) in some citations to corroborate some of these claims. In particular, I'm very curious to know when Shazam has been shown/stated to be able to keep up with the Flashes, and when he's been shown/stated to be faster than Superman.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to have a lot of questions of your own, and no clear answer to the question.  If you have questions you should [ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) them; you should edit this down to a clear answer to the question with as much supporting evidence as you can find.  Please read [answer].